# Autocomplete environments like in TeXStudio

Tags: latex, auctex, yasnippet

[TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) autocompletes environments.  How can I get AUCTeX to do the same?

I can begin typing an environment name (say `myenvironment`) and, after entering a part of it (`my`, `myenv`, etc.), I hit <kbd>Control-Alt-Space</kbd>, and TeXStudio autocompletes the environment (asking if there are multiple possibilities), and sets the point between `\begin{myenvironment}` and `\end{myenvironment}`.

I tried `yasnippet` mode, but this works only for predefined snippets. So I have, for example, to define a keyword `myenv` and it will only autocomplete the snippet for the environment if `myenv + TAB` is entered and not when only `my + TAB` is entered (with a list of possible completions) or if I type `myenvi + TAB`.

I also tried `predictive-mode` which seems to complete only words.

*EDIT:* I know the AUCTeX way to do this via `C-c C-e`. The difference to the desired TeXStudio approach is that you have to give a key sequence first and then input a few letters of the environment name, whereas in TeXStudio it is the other way around (which is what I am asking here).

Comment: Both company-mode and auto-complete-mode offer integration for yasnippet, perhaps that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Auctex provides environment completion with the function `M-x LaTeX-environment` by default bound to `C-c C-e`. The details are provided in the [fine manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Environments.html).

Comment: Thanks. But that's not exactly what I asked for. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

@Tyler's answer (`C-c C-e`) is the simplest and most straightforward way to get environments insofar as it's the built-in way to use AUCTeX's functionality.  Since it gets you 99% of the way there, it seems like the way to go unless you *really* need to do it auto-complete style.

If you really wanted to, you could wrap that command in a snippet so that you could invoke it while typing (here, as `,env TAB`):

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: environment
# key: ,env
# type: command
# --
(call-interactively #'LaTeX-environment)
```

Of course, that's little more than a change of keybindings. (I use the snippet to minimize use of the <kbd>Control</kbd> key, but YMMV.)  If, however, you're using `ido-mode` (and particularly `ido-vertical-mode`), it'll make the completion experience much more pleasant in either the stock (`C-c C-e`) or snippet version.

Answer (score 1):

The command `LaTeX-insert-environment-at-point` defined below tries to complete an environment name at point. If the prefix is ambiguous, it pulls up the same list of completions as `C-x C-e` does. If AUCTeX knows about the environment, you may be prompted for parameters (same as with `C-x C-e`). As a bonus, if the name is preceded by a backslash, insert a command instead. Bind it to the key of your choice.

```
(defvar LaTeX-environment-name-characters
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789*")
(defun LaTeX-insert-environment-at-point ()
  "Insert \begin{ENVIRONMENT}...\end{ENVIRONMENT}, completing the word at point.
If the word at point is preceded by a backslash, complete a macro name instead,
like \\[TeX-insert-macro].
The customization possibilities are the same as \\[LaTeX-environment]."
  (interactive "@*")
  (save-match-data
    (let* ((prefix-start (save-excursion
                           (skip-chars-backward LaTeX-environment-name-characters)
                           (point)))
           (backslash (and (> prefix-start (point-min))
                           (= (char-after (1- prefix-start)) ?\\)))
           (completions (if backslash
                            (TeX-symbol-list)
                          (LaTeX-environment-list)))
           (prefix (buffer-substring-no-properties prefix-start (point)))
           (matches (remove-if-not (lambda (entry)
                                     (string-prefix-p prefix entry))
                                   (mapcar #'car completions)))
           (name (case (length matches)
                   ((0)
                    (error "No environment name begins with %s" prefix))
                   ((1)
                    (car matches))
                   (t
                    ;; Gross hack: arrange to show the list of completions,
                    ;; by pushing a `minibuffer-complete' event (assuming
                    ;; default key bindings).
                    (setq unread-command-events (cons 'tab unread-command-events))
                    (completing-read (if backslash "Macro: "
                                       "Environment type: ")
                                     completions
                                     nil
                                     nil
                                     prefix
                                     (if backslash
                                         'TeX-macro-history
                                       'LaTeX-environment-history))))))
      (delete-region prefix-start (point))
      (funcall (if backslash #'TeX-insert-macro #'LaTeX-environment-menu) name))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but, I got the following error message: `Mark set
completing-read-default: Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer
Quit [2 times]
Mark set
Mark saved where search started
let*: Symbol's function definition is void: remove-if-not`

Answer (score 0):

To get such behaviour, you an use [helm-c-yasnippet](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-c-yasnippet). Using the command `helm-yas-complete` in you case, it will do exactly what you want: gives a list of candidates available in `yasnippet` that start with the supplied prefix.

By default, `yasnippet` is bundled with common snippets. You can load more snippets with [yasnippets-latex](https://github.com/madsdk/yasnippets-latex).

Comment: Interesting.  Would this not require you to have all of the snippets pre-defined, however?

Comment: Yes. Here are the default [predefined templates in yasnippet](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/tree/master/latex-mode). At least you have all the standard environments. Maybe if someone creates `helm-auctex-environment`, then we will have something similar to `helm-yas-complete` without predefining templates.